# What would the effects of simultaneous heating of the human body be?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, magic, hard-science, balancing-magic-systems

Though this has to deal with a magic system, the 'magic' part isn't relevant. Suppose, due to the magic, the human body heats up at a rate of **x** watts, for a total of **T** kilo-joules, what would the effects be, **AND** how would  directing some of this heat to the outer 10% of the body (and also away from the brain) affect it?

(Note that this redirecting only works for internal heat; If the heat is external and entering the body, nothing can be done about it.)

### Specifically, I need solutions to these three cases-

(A solution consists of possible ranges of **x** and **T**. Either as an equation, or a graph would be preferable, but since that is not easy to do on stack exchange, just an idea of how I can calculate said ranges would be extremely helpful)

a) **The Average Person**:

The average person is untrained in magic, and thus uses it rarely, and his **x** and **T** values differ from those of a skilled practitioner. However, the question deals not with that, simply with a range.

- Now, the goal of this person would be to use magic in such a way that he does not suffer any crippling, permanent damage afterwards
- However, short term damage is not a problem. If he is unconscious for three days, but has no problem for the rest of his life, the condition is satisfied. He should, however, remain conscious for a few (let's say 5) minutes while the magic is active.
- He has no ability whatsoever to redirect heat to his outer parts. His brain heats up at practically the same rate as his legs.

b) **The Trained Soldier**:

More skilled, he uses magic on a daily basis in battlefield situations and while training. Thus, he has different conditions than the average person.

- He also does not want to suffer crippling damage, but if worst comes to worst, he could use magic in a way that causes his death 10 years down the line if he survives today. Today is a priority; tomorrow is not.
- However he absolutely wants minimum short term effects. He needs to remain conscious, and maximise the time he spends on the battlefield while more powered. At the minimum, he needs at least 15 minutes of magic use, while maintaining consciousness for at least an hour afterwards (optimally. If afterwards he falls down, it is not a failed case, but I still need a solution to the previous case. This case only works in a desperate battle).
- He can redirect around 50% of the heat to his outer parts. He can also redirect 90% of the heat away from the brain ie the brain heats up at 20% the rate the heart does and 10% the rate the legs  or hands do.
- He has more psychological and physiological training than the average guy, and can thus stay conscious in conditions where the average person would not, but tends to avoid such extreme conditions.

c) **The Suicidal Hero**:
He has the same specifications as the last two points of the soldier. The difference? He wants to go out with a bang. He doesn't need to survive afterwards, just do as much damage as possible.

- In this case, I do not need a survivable range, but an optimal one, such that the soldier stays alive for as long as possible. Since we expect a LOT of energy involved, expect the ranges to be much higher than the other two. To pin down a minimum case, time should be between 30 secs to 2 mins, **T** should between 10x and 20x of the survivable **T**.
- This is not a necessary case, at least now. If this is hard to do, I just need equations for the other two, and using equations for the minimum magical output (which tell the amount of magic he'd use, to help pin down a minimum case for this), I can figure out what ranges I expect this guy to be in.

Bonus case: When these soldiers (case B and C) are elite mages who can redirect 90% of the heat to the outer parts, and have the head heat up at 2-5% of the normal rate. So basically the answer to B and C when 50% is replaced with 90% and the head heating rate is also reduced to 2-5% from 10%. In case you have an equation, this would be much easier to solve for.

### Additional Note:

I did not mention this since this is an addon, and a way to solve the former would probably solve the latter, but in the actual case, there are two states: Magic ON and Magic OFF.

- During Magic ON, the body heats up at **x** watts, and **T** increases at **r** watts. (In practice, **T** increases at **r** - **x** watts, since **x** is being removed from **T** and added to the body)
- During Magic OFF, **T** does not increase, but gets added to the body at **y**, which is less than **x**. (You heat up slower during OFF than when ON)
- **T** carries over between spells. You can't start a new spell and see your **T** vanish.

### Here is all the research that I have done:

Before starting, [THIS](https://www.zuniv.net/physiology/book/chapter21.html) might be very helpful (Or not. I am no medical student, so someone with a better head for that is far better suited here). I went through it, but not being an expert, I think further solution may be found using the article's resources.

Now, the average specific heat capacity of a human is 3.49 kJ/kg. For someone of mass **K** kg, (We can take it 60 later to simplify calculations).Now, taking (3.49 * **K**) as **g**, this means that the person using magic will heat up by a total of **T**/**g** degrees, at a rate of **x**/**g** watts. (Do confirm this please)

However, I cannot calculate the body's response/survivability very well, which is why I asked it here. Answers must be a solution to the above mentioned cases, and it would be great if it did so for the bonus case to. Barring that, showing me a clear path to the solution shall suffice.

### Thanks a lot.

P.S. - The **T** here is not equal to the actual amount of work done by the magic, only how much the body heats (It *is* related ie greater **T** means more powerful magic. But it is not equal to it). So I do not want answers saying "To survive for any period of time, **T** and **x** have to be so microscopic that the magic done would be useless." The person might heat by 0.5 K, while the magic might lift a mountain. That last part is up to me to decide.

P.P.S. - However, observations of loophole abuse are welcome.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. The human body *already has* mechanisms to shed waste heat. The amount of heat produced by the body varies considerably between rest and strenuous exercise; as in, from about 100 W to about 300 W. Yet the core temperature is kept almost constant, because the human body actively works to shed waste heat. All in all, your magic users can deal with about 200 W extra heat produced by magic, because their bodies *already have* this functionality built in. If it is more than that, or if they are in unfavorable conditions, then tough luck, they overheat and die.

Comment: Of course, they don't overheat *instantly*. By and large, the body can wave away an increase in core temperature by 1 K, will suffer it it increases by 2 K, will suffer and may die if it increase by 3 K and *will* die if it increases by 4 K. Since most of the body is water, you can easily compute how much energy this represents.

Comment: this really needs to be broken up into sperate questions, how heating different parts of the body the body will kill is  more than enough for one question. And a lot of the other things seem like things that are up to you to decide.